# Android: Image displayed at Webview from Url with high quality loss

Tags: android, image, webview

I want to display an image from an url with an Webview at Android.

With Android phones with Version 1.5 and 1.6 there is no problem. but the same pic and the same code on an AndroidPhone with Version 2.0 and the pic is totaly pixelated.

Like Android is resizing the image first to a smaller one and then resizing it back to "normal" size.

Unfortunately its important to display the pic without any quality loss.

I tried to integrate it in the sourcefolder to show it as an normal image, but at Android 2.0 i get an exception because the image is to big. (At Android 1.6 there is no problem)

Any ideas how i can display the image without quality loss with Android 2.0 ?

Comment: You might consider posting a URL to the image in question.

Answer (score 3):

If you have not already done it, add this to your manifest :

```
 <supports-screens
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:resizeable="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Without this, everything will be scaled.

Also, if you dont want your device/emulator to scale your drawables you have to create drawables for each density by putting a higher resolution version into hdpi folder

```
res/drawable-ldpi/my_icon.png       // icon image for low density
res/drawable-mdpi/dpi/my_icon.png   // icon for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png       // icon image for high density
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but whenever i try to add "android:resizable=true" there is an error. It seems he doesnt know this parameter. Or do i have to add something other too ? I tried with minSdkVersion = 4.

Comment: I dont think there should be anything more needed to make resizable=true work. I use minSdk 3 and targetSdk=5... but i dont think that should make any difference. Im using <uses-sdk 
  android:minSdkVersion="3" 
  android:targetSdkVersion="5" />

Comment: What happens if you try to add an ImageView with an image, does the ImageView also get scaled. Do you see any artifacts on the image ? (just to test if your app is scaling the view or not)

Comment: imageview works fine wehen the file is in the source and small enough. If not i get an out of memory exception. That was the reason i tried to display the image with an webview. 

i don get why i cant use resizable... whenever i try, i get "ERROR No resource identifier found for attribute 'resizable' in package 'android'"

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:resizeable="true"` instead of `android:resizable="true"`.
There is a missing `"e"`.

Comment: No?  This says it's `resizable`: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Long time this thread is here but here are my two cents :

Doing the same thing it took me two days to figure out what my problem was :

On one of my phone I was using wifi, on the other one I was connected on edge via my carrier.

Turns out most carriers around the world use a proxy that downsize images on the fly to lighten the burden on the network. The downsizing is pretty hard and the quality is very bad.

So that in my case it was not due to the framework version as I thought but by the type of connection I used.

Comment: I downloaded an image from the net. If I open the local file in a webview it is pixelated. If I open the file in an imageview it is not pixelated anymore, but I cant zoom anymore.

Comment: This probably due to the fact that the request made by the webview contains the mime type which is used by the isp to trigger the downscale. While the imageview probably asks for a binary transfert. Not sure though. Just so you know, it is possible to use the image you downloaded to create a local html file that you would display in the webview gaining the zoom ability back. Kind of cumbersome but it works. Or you could take a look at : http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I believe it's a strange behavior of WebView control. There's a small workaround that is useful in case when you supply the images via your own server. If the image is in PNG format, you can set color depth to 8 bit. Though it will decrease color quality, the image won't be blurred when zoomed in.

Comment: Indeed 8 bit color depth helps to reduce memory usage but still has a chance to lose quantity when image size is too big.