# Logo on website in webview displays in low quality

Tags: android, image, webview

NOTE: this issue only occurs on certain android devices (note 2, s4), looks like only on samsung devices but cannot confirm this 100%

So I needed to load a mobile website inside a webview, now the logo in the header of the website gets displayed very pixelated, like it was downsized and then upscaled...

I tried everything: transparent png, jpg with correct background, svg, bigger image, perfect size image, smaller image,... Image didn't went over 10kb.

Any idea what could go wrong...

EDIT: included screenshot
On the left the icon showed on HTC One, HTC One X, Nexus 4, Nexus One
Right: Samsung Galaxy S4 and Note 2

[image: Left: HTC One + HTC One X + ..., Right: Samsung S4, Note 2]

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460928/android-image-displayed-at-webview-from-url-with-high-quality-loss

Comment: Thanks for the help, but tried this already...

Comment: Could you please paste the original image and the distorted one ?

Comment: are you using 3g? it could be an invisible proxy...

Comment: @g00dy: Added screenshot...

Comment: @Pork: No, tested on wifi, tested on devices after factory reset, so no proxy I guess

Comment: Try putting this into the manifest `<supports-screens
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:resizeable="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />` with it, the images will not be resized (if you have different ones for different densities and resolutions etc.).